# Django signal user_login_failed not working for Custom User model , Custom Backend

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication, django-signals

I am a beginner in Django and due to my project requirements, I came to conclusion that I have to implement Custom User model, and also due to this I also implemented Custom Backend.
But, now I am unable to use user_login_failed Django Signal, as I am thinking to use it for restrict the user login attempt to 3.

Any help will be a great deal to me
Thanks

Signals.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import (user_logged_in,
                                        user_logged_out,
                                        user_login_failed)
# from accounts.models import Usermanagement
# from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import F
from django.dispatch import receiver


Usermanagement = get_user_model()
# Usermanagement = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
print("Sgnals usermanagement: ",Usermanagement)

@receiver(user_logged_in,sender=Usermanagement)
def login_success(sender,request,user, **kwargs):
    print("-------------------------")
    print("Login Success Signal...")
    print("Sender: ", sender)
    print("Request: ", request)
    print("Username: ",user.email)
    print("Password: ",user.password)
    print(f"Kwargs: {kwargs}")

@receiver(user_login_failed,sender=Usermanagement)
def login_failed(sender,credentials,request,**kwargs):
    # User = UserManagement()
    print("-------------------------")
    print("Login failed Signal...")
    print("Sender: ", sender)
    print("Credentials: ", credentials)
    print("Request: ", request)
    # print("Email: ", email)
    print(f"Kwargs: {kwargs}")

# @receiver(user_logged_out,sender=Usermanagement)
# def logout_success()
```

apps.py

```
# apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'accounts'

    def ready(self):
        import accounts.signals
```

**init**.py

```
# __init__.py

default_app_config = "accounts.apps.AccountsConfig"
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Usermanagement'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'accounts.backends.EmailAuthBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

modely.py

```
class Usermanagement(AbstractBaseUser):

 emailid = models.CharField(db_column='EmailID', unique=True, max_length=45,default=1)
 ------------
 ---------
 -----------

 objects = UsermanagementCustomUserManager()

 USERNAME_FIELD = "emailid"
 EMAIL_FIELD = "emailid"
```

managers.py

```
class UsermanagementCustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,emailid,firstname, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not emailid:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            emailid=self.normalize_email(emailid),
            password=password,

        )

        user.set_password(password) 
        user.save(using=self._db) 
        return user
```

backends.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password,check_password
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

Usermanagement = get_user_model()



class EmailAuthBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self,request,username=None,password=None):
        # print("Custom authenticate rqst: ",request)
        try:
            print("Trying the email backend!")
            user = Usermanagement.objects.get(emailid=username)
            print("Got the user")
            # print(password)
            # print(user.password)
            # print(check_password(password))
            # print(user.check_password(password))


            if user.password == password or user.check_password(password):
                return user
            
        except user.DoesNotExist:
            return None
    
    def get_user(self,user_id): 
        try:
            print("Getting the user of the Email Bkacned")
            return Usermanagement.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except Usermanagement.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout ,authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm


def loginPage(request):
    # POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request,data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid(): 
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            #Check
            print("EMAIL: ",email)
            print("PASSWORD: ",password)
            # Authentication USER
            user = authenticate(request,username=email,password=password)
            print("Authenticated ",user) # Check
            # check
            print(user)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user,backend='accounts.backends.EmailAuthBackend')
                # messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {email}.")
                    return redirect("home")
                else:
                    pass

            else: # If User Not found
                # messages.error(request,"User not found")
                # return HttpResponse("User not found, not able to login")
                pass

        else: # Form InValid
            # messages.error(request,"Invalid username or password.")
            # return HttpResponse("Form Invalid")
            context = {
                "form" : form
            }
            return render(request,"loginPage.html",context=context)
    # GET
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        context = {"form":form}
        return render(request,"loginPage.html",context=context)
```

my code was working fine until I switched to Custom User model and Custom Authentication backend

Comment: Well have you imported your `signals.py` in the app config's ready method or somewhere else? Django doesn't have a builtin way where it imports that file you see so it might be that your code for the signals never ran.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat         sorry, I forgot to add the "apps.py" and "__init__.py", now i have edited my Questions. if you require more details of my code i will edit my Question for sure

Comment: Oh, you've mentioned `sender=Usermanagement` that's the problem. The model isn't used for the sender for this signal (Because well user's can be authenticated without a model class so until Django get's a user object it can't provide a user class as the sender)

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_login_failed) the sender for the `user_login_failed` signal is:

> The name of the module used for authentication.

That means `sender=Usermanagement` is incorrect, the reason for this is that people can have various strategies for authentication (i.e. backends) these might or might not use a user model so until the user is authenticated there's no way Django can know what model class it should use as a sender. Given that the authentication failed Django simply sends the name of the current module as the sender.

You can simply skip the `sender` argument in your case and it should work fine:

```py
@receiver(user_login_failed)
def login_failed(sender,credentials,request,**kwargs):
    ...
```